# How to properly reference local document when rendering a React component in an iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-dom

I have a component that calls the `document` global. When I render this component in an iframe, it uses the current (parent) document as a reference, not the document of the iframe.

```tsx
export const Modal: FC<ModalProps> = ({ opened, ...props }) => {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // Prevent background scrolling when the modal is opened.
    // This line locks scroll on the main DOM, but I only want it to be blocked on the iframe.
    document.body.style.overflow = opened ? "hidden" : "";
  }, [opened]); 

  // ...
}
```

Can I render the `Modal` component, so that `document` refers to the iframe document (and not the main DOM) ?

I use this custom component to render React elements in a separate iframe:

```tsx
import { FC, DetailedHTMLProps, IframeHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export const IFrame: FC<DetailedHTMLProps<IframeHTMLAttributes<HTMLIFrameElement>, HTMLIFrameElement>> = ({ children, style, ...props }) => {
  const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState<HTMLIFrameElement | null>(null);
  const headNode = useMemo(() => contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.head, [contentRef]);
  const mountNode = useMemo(() => contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body, [contentRef]);

  // Setup head.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (headNode) {
      // Inherit parent styles (like compiled css modules or local fonts).
      for (const style of Array.from(document.head.querySelectorAll("link"))) {
        headNode.appendChild(style.cloneNode(true));
      }
      for (const style of Array.from(document.head.querySelectorAll("style"))) {
        headNode.appendChild(style.cloneNode(true));
      }
    }
  }, [headNode]);

  return (
    <>
      <iframe
        {...props}
        style={{ border: "none", ...style }}
        ref={setContentRef}
      />
      {mountNode ? createPortal(children, mountNode) : null}
    </>
  );
});
```

I also tried to create a new root and render the children inside, but it doesn't work either.

```tsx
useEffect(() => {
  if (mountNode) {
    const root = createRoot(mountNode);
    root.render(children);

    return () => {
      root.unmount();
    };
  }
}, [mountNode]);

return (
  <iframe
    {...props}     
    style={{ border: "none", ...style }}
    ref={setContentRef}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no one else has had a go at this, please excuse a little speculation in this answer.

What I think is happening here is that when you put content inside react’s `<iframe>` element it is creating your content using the `srcdoc` attribute, rather than the more normal `src`. This is then leading to your iframed content to exist in the same DOM context as your parent page.

To fix this I think you either need to force React to load a new page into your iframe, or instead store the contextual data your after inside this component and pass a setState method to your child nodes.